# Force NAT UPNP port forwarding

Tags: c#, port, upnp

I would like to forward ports automatically with my application, however UPNP is off by default, but Spotify was able to forward ports when even UPNP is disabled, same applies to uTorrent and others.

How do I force port forwarding, or Enable UPNP on rounter, forward port and disable it again?

Comment: Possibly a daft question but how do you know that Spotify is forwarding ports?  It could conceivably work by making an outbound connection from your network to an external server, relying on routers only blocking incoming connections.

Comment: I can see it on web site of router, where you can manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these services use UDP hole punching.

See: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

Comment: Okay, then it sounds like NAT Port Mapping Protocol. But I don't know if it's disabled when UPnP is disabled too.